# Replace value of an element with a value from sitecore variable

Tags: configuration

I have a variables.config file where i have all the variables and corresponding values stored like shown below:

[image]

This is default sitecore file :
[image]
Now i want to replace the value 1000 with the value stored in the Variables.config file
Now i am trying with this:
[image]

But this is not working.

Comment: did you include the the Variable.config in the Sitecore.config file?

Comment: Variable replacement often doesn't work that way. Sometimes you can get lucky and try this (works on pipelines)... <policy batchSize="$(otap-batch-size)" ...><Limit>$(batchSize)</Limit></policy>.

Comment: @Hishaam yeah,i can see the variable in showconfig

Comment: @jrap i tried your suggestion. It replaces attribute value but not value of the element

Comment: Then it's not supported. I have done extensive testing of the method I suggested and some elements support it, others do not. I never dug into the details as to why it _sometimes_ works and why it doesn't other times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use Sitecore config variables in this way to set replacement values. The global config variable replacement process only works on node attributes, e.g. `<setting name="xyz" value="$(variable)" />`. It will not work on element values, e.g. `<element>$(value)</element>`.

You will find some elements in the Sitecore config which *appear to look* like a global variables, but checking the expanded config in **"/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx"** you will note that they have **not** been expanded by the `ConfigReader` and in fact the replacements is made by the underlying code used by that process (`Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.DumpConfigurationFiles` processor is a good example of this).

For the replacement of the `<Limit>` node, in your case you should use a regular config patch which target's this element:

```xml
<contentSearch>
  <configuration>
    <indexes>
      <index id="sitecore_web_index">
        <commitPolicyExecutor>
          <policies>
            <policy>
              <Limit>1000</Limit>
            </policy>
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```